# Ruby - Read file and print line number

Tags: ruby, file

This isn't going to be easy to explain and I haven't found any answers for it.

I want to be able to read .txt file in Ruby and somehow be able to print the line number.

Example:

```
#file.txt:
#Hello
#My name is John Smith
#How are you?

File.open("file.txt").each do |line|
   puts line
   puts line.linenumber
end

#First Iteration outputs
#=> Hello
#=> 1

#Second Iteration outputs
#=> My name is John Smith
#=> 2

#Third Iteration outputs
#=> How are you?
#=> 3
```

I hope this makes sense and I hope it's easily possible.

Thanks in advance,
Reece

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby, like Perl, has the special variable `$.` which contains the line number of a file.

```
File.open("file.txt").each do |line|
   puts line, $.
end
```

Prints:

```
#Hello
1
#My name is John Smith
2
#How are you?
3
```

Strip the `\n` from `line` if you want the number on the same line:

```
File.open("file.txt").each do |line|
   puts "#{line.rstrip} #{$.}"
end

#Hello 1
#My name is John Smith 2
#How are you? 3
```

---

As stated in comments, rather than use `File.open` you can use [File.foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) with the benefit of autoclose at the end of the block:

```
File.foreach('file.txt') do |line|
    puts line, $.
end 
# same output...
```

Comment: `File.foreach` might be better here as `File.open(#...).each` will leave the file open until the GC gets around to disposing of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):

> Calls block with two arguments, the item and its index, for each item
>   in enum. Given arguments are passed through to each().

```
File.open(filename).each_with_index do |line, index|
  p "#{index} #{line}"
end
```

Comment: To get the example output in the post, ('First interaction, 1') you need to add 1 to index.

Comment: Not a problem @dawg. There's also a [`with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) method for that.